# Getting value from parameter of this method and displaying it

Tags: java, android, xml, parameters, int

I want to get the values from all 4 rows of the wheel, and display the value into a textview or a toast.
My testwheelvalue(,)method is suppose to get the value off the face of the wheel, and return that value to my method testpin().  After testpin() stores the values into v1-v4 the method updatestatus() should display the sum of the value into the textfield.

public class PasswActivity extends Activity {

```
    int testpins;
    int v1 = 0;
    int v2 = 0;
    int v3 = 0;
    int v4 = 0;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.passw_layout);
        initWheelday(R.id.passw_1);
        initWheelhour(R.id.passw_2);
        initWheelmin(R.id.passw_3);
        initWheelsec(R.id.passw_4);

        updateStatus();
    }

    // Wheel scrolled flag
    private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

    // Wheel scrolled listener
    OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {
            wheelScrolled = true;
        }

        public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {
            wheelScrolled = false;
            updateStatus();
        }
    };

    // Wheel changed listener
    private OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
        public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            if (!wheelScrolled) {
                updateStatus();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Updates entered PIN status
     */
    private void updateStatus() {
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);
        testPin();

        text.setText(String.valueOf(testpins));
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), testpins,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes wheel
     * 
     * @param id
     *            the wheel widget Id
     */
    private void initWheelsec(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 59, "%02d"));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));

    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(false);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
}

private void initWheelmin(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 59, "%02d"));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));

    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(false);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
}

private void initWheelhour(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 23, "%02d"));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));

    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(false);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
}

private void initWheelday(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 5, "%02d"));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));

    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(false);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
}


    /**
     * Returns wheel by Id
     * 
     * @param id
     *            the wheel Id
     * @return the wheel with passed Id
     */
    private WheelView getWheel(int id) {
        return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
    }

    /**
     * Tests entered PIN
     * 
     * @param v1
     * @param v2
     * @param v3
     * @param v4
     * @return true
     */
    private void testPin() {

        v1 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_1, v1);
        v2 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_2, v2);
        v3 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_3, v3);
        v4 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_4, v4);
        testpins = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
    }

    /**
     * Tests wheel value
     * 
     * @param id
     *            the wheel Id
     * @param value
     *            the value to test
     * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
     */
    private int testWheelValue(int id, int value) {
        int wheel = getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
        wheel = value;
        text.setText(String.valueOf(testpins));
        return wheel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Besides the question what is the code of `getWheel(int)` I don't really understand what you want to do. I see you use `setText()` and assume `text` is some kind of textView. Does it not print what you expect?

Comment: It prints out a 0. I want it to print out the sum of all the values held in v1-v4.

Comment: Have a look at Eric's answer. As he stated you never change the values held in v1 - v4 and as they all are initialised with 0 the sum is 0. magic? No, maths ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void testPin() {

    v1 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_1, v1);
    v2 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_2, v2);
    v3 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_3, v3);
    v4 testWheelValue(R.id.passw_4, v4);
```

You are missing an `=` on each of the four lines above, but I'll assume that's just a cut and paste error.

```
    testpins = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
```

I'd do `return v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;` and get rid of the `testpins` class member.

```
}

/**
 * Tests wheel value
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel Id
 * @param value
 *            the value to test
 * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
 */
private int testWheelValue(int id, int value) {
    int wheel = getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
    wheel = value;
```

Delete that line, as you are overwriting the value you are reading. Furthermore, `int value` is not needed as a parameter.

```
    text.setText(String.valueOf(testpins));
```

Get rid of this line as `updateStatus()` does that in the correct place. `text` is also another unnecessary class member - it should be local to `updateStatus()`.

```
    return wheel;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I was able to clean up my code and make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

All your `testWheelValue` does is compare the value of an ID and one of your `v` parameters, then returns the equality. If you want your `v` parameters to be overwritten by something, you need to tell the program so:

```
v1 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_1); // You don't need to pass anything but the ID here
v2 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_2);
v3 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_3);
v4 = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_4);

testpins = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
updateStatus();

// This method should just use getCurrentItem from the WheelView
private int getWheelValue(int id) {
    return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
}
```

This way, the new value of the `v` parameter gets passed back into the main code.

Comment: You are right.  I changed up the values from boolean to int and i am playign around with it.  I'll keep you updated.

Comment: It's still not returning 0 instead of the true values of v1,v2,v3 and v4. I updated my code.

Comment: Does this also mean i have to change my testpin() method?

Comment: Yes. See all those assignments you have commented out? `/*v1=*/` and such? Remove the `/* */`. Additionally, I think the logic in your `testWheelValue` method is incorrect. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I clerified what my methods are suppose to do in the question.  I also tried to post a screenshot, but stackoverflow said my reputation must be at least 10.  I guess they didnt take into account how much im offering for this bounty.

Comment: I've updated my code above to conform to the changes in your question. As far as I can tell, this should work exactly as you expect.